# Single Page Website module - anchors not displayed in the browser address bar

Tags: panels

I installed the module https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_website in Drupal 7. When I click the menu items it scrolls to the pages as it is expected, but then the anchors are not displayed in the browser address bar.
All the time the adress of the site is displayed without anchors. So the address is not changing during scrolling to the pages. ('Pages' is the Panels element so I do not mean normal pages because all is acting in the single page.)
The links in the menu have the ahchors.
How can I enable the anchors in the browser address bar?

Comment: I deleted my earlier comments because they sounded too emphatic (sorry). This module has every indication of being unmaintained. It’s unlikely you will have good experiences using it. You should include the precise module version in your question. It looks as though the dev version had commits as recently as 2019 so that may be your best chance.

Comment: I used the recent dev version and that helped. Thank you